# Detailed Reporting Cypress/Mochawesome

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

Has anyone had much experience of generating good detailed reports from Cypress tests using *Mochawesome* as the report engine?

I've followed the info on the Mochawesome GIT page but what I get is rather dull!!

[image: Current Report]

I'd like to be able to include the odd screen-shot and the output from the assertions - here's the current `cypress.json` file......

```
{
 "projectId": "haw8v6",
"baseUrl": "https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/",
"chromeWebSecurity": false,
"reporter" : "mochawesome",
 "reporterOptions" : {
"reportFilename" : "DBM Smoke-Test",
"overwrite": true,
"inline": true

}
}
```

I've been toying with `var addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');` but with little joy.

Suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks

As per request below - very basic example of `addContext`

```
var addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

describe('DBM Smoketests', function() {
it('E2E Hotel2 WorldPay System', function() {
    cy.visit('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/');


                    cy.url().should('include','/obmng.dbm');
                    addContext(this,'URL is correct');

 //loads hotel 2 
    cy.get('.jss189 > div > .jss69 > .jss230').click();
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you show your usage of `addContext` in your tests.

Comment: Thanks @HiramK.Hackenbacker...please see above for a very basic example.

Comment: Ok that was simpler that I anticipated. I guess the premise is, if it gets to that line the one above has succeeded.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker - yes...just trying to get things to work thus far...so why is there nothing showing on the report for this `addContext`? Have I missed a setting in `cypress.json`?

Comment: Try this method, it will work 100%, https://softans.com/using-mochawesome-reporter-with-cypress/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much hacking about, I found a way to use Mochawesome `addContext` in Cypress.

Note, you can only make one addContext call per test (this is a Mochawesome limitation).

```js
describe('DBM Smoketests', function() {
  it('E2E Hotel2 WorldPay System', function() {
    cy.visit('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/');
    cy.url().should('include','/obmng.dbm');

    Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {
      addContext({ test }, { 
        title: 'This is my context title', 
        value: 'This is my context value'
      })
    });
  });
});
```

The second param is the context to be attached to the test, and it must have non-empty `title` and a `value` properties.

What you get in the `mochawesome.json` output is

```json
...
"suites": [
  {
    ...
    "tests": [
      {
        "title": "E2E Hotel2 WorldPay System",
        ...
        "context": "{\n  \"title\": \"This is my context title\",\n  \"value\": \"This is my context value\"\n}",
        "code": "...",
        ...
      }
    ],
```

In `mochawesome.html`, on clicking the test you get

```txt
Additional Test Context
This is my context title:
This is my context value
```

I have not tried it out with value types other than string.

**Note** for anyone starting out with Mochawesome in Cypress, it looks like you can only get a Mochawesome report with running `cypress run`, not with `cypress open` - although there may be a way around this using mocha's multiple reporter functionality.

Comment: Thanks Hiram - that's a big help! I was used to the joys of Jasmine Beautiful Reporter but your advice will go a long way to get me moving. Is there are better reporter to use with Cypress do you think?

Comment: Like yourself, I am evaluating options. I must admit I quite like the Mochawesome presentation. The other good thing is it produces `json`, so with a bit of programming it can be presented in any form that appeals.

Comment: See [Unable to add extra information to mocha test object #1910](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1910), I am not sure how much attention Cypress will give small issues around third party reporting. They have the Mochawesome box ticked, so I think that is their main concern. Other reporters may be more difficult for us to use, which is a pity.

Comment: Agreed Hiram! I know my own Dev colleagues tend to use Cypress for their Unit Tests where reporting is not required - console output is fine for them....but for QA, we **do** need some decent reporting that's shareable with non-specialists.

Comment: Hi @HiramK.Hackenbacker, great answer! Another thing that caught my attention is your Note wherein you mentioned that generating cypress reports through cypress run wasn't possible as of then. Do you have any information on the current status, whether we can generate it now? 
I have asked a question on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628788/cypress-report-not-generating-while-running-tests-through-cypress-test-runner

Comment: It appears you can addContext multiple times depending on whether you use ES5 or ES6 syntax? https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome#example

Answer (score 3):

Yes confirmed work! It's possible to call once in each test like this:

```
it('Should shine the test report!!!', () => {
  cy.get('li').should('have.length.greaterThan', 0);
  addTestContext('String','giphy');
  addTestContext('Link','https://giphy.com');
  addTestContext('Image','https://media.giphy.com/media/tIIdsiWAaBNYY/giphy.gif');
  addTestContext('Image','https://media.giphy.com/media/tIIdsiWAaBNYY/giphy.gif');
});

function addTestContext(title, value) {
  cy.once('test:after:run', test => addContext({ test }, { title, value }));
}
```