# Export the test results to HTML in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is there any way the `test results` in Cypress can be exported to an HTML or any other format ( *like cucumber-report.html*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `mochawesome` reporter to run to export the report. But the caveat is mochawesome when used alone generates individual reports which get overridden by the latest spec file that is run. In order to merge all the individual `mochawesome` reports, give a shot to `mochawesome-merge` which will combine all the test results and export it in HTML.

Towards that end,

1. Install `mocha`, `mochawesome` and `mochawesome-merge` (mochawesome has peer dependency on mocha)

> ```
> npm install mocha
> npm install mochawesome --save-dev
> npm install mochawesome-merge --save-dev
> ```

2. In the `cypress.json`, paste the following config:

> 

```
{
      "reporter": "mochawesome",
     "reporterOptions": {
       "charts": true,
       "overwrite": false,
       "html": false,
       "json": true,
       "reportDir": "cypress/report/mochawesome-report"
      }
    }
```

3. Run Cypress

> `npx cypress run --reporter mochawesome`

4. Once all tests are run, merge the reports into a single one

> `npx mochawesome-merge cypress/report/mochawesome-report/*.json > cypress/report/output.json`

5. Now convert the JSON into HTML

> `npx marge cypress/report/output.json --reportDir ./ --inline`

6. Once the HTML report is generated, you will see something like this:

> ✓ Reports saved:
> E:\Project_Path\cypress\report\output.html

Comment: Are you testing on windows? I am getting **Error: ." --inline contains invalid WIN32 path characters.** when running `npx marge cypress/report/output.json --reportDir ./ --inline`

Comment: Also, subsequent runs are producing duplicate json (same content but '_001' suffix) which will lead to the tests showing twice on the HTML. Perhaps you need a rim-raf step?

Comment: @AloysiusParker Yes I was running on Windows. And in my end, I was not experiencing duplicate data issue. Can you please recheck the reporter configurations? Also Ensure you have Node version higher than 8

Comment: +1! For merging the reports into a single one, it is better to use `-o cypress/report/output.json` shell output redirection (`> cypress/report/output.json`) since shell output redirection will include yarn timing info (if you are using yarn).

Comment: @MitchellTracy That's a great suggestion! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any mocha reporter as cypress is build on top of it: https://mochajs.org/#reporters spec reporter is the default one.

You will have to add them to your cypress.json config like this:

```
{
  "reporter": "mochawesome" 
}
```

You can find all the information here: [Reporters](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Custom-Reporters)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that today and reply back.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will have to add to your project dev dependencies `mocha` and `mochawesome`. Refer to their documentation for full details

Comment: I have installed `npm install --save-dev mochawesome` and added the `"reporter": "mochawesome"` in cypress.json file, but it failed to run in headless mode and can't find the relevant files

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343181/detailed-reporting-cypress-mochawesome) for some additional info.

Comment: Your will also have to install `mocha` as a peer dependency of your project in order to run `mochawesome`. Can you post the errors thrown to you?